# Q function that computes the value

Tags: kdb

How would I write a function in q/kdb that computes the value in a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
q)l:1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 1 2 7 6 4
q)where max[a]=a:count each group l
1 2
q)min where max[a]=a:count each group l
1
q)mode:{where max[a]=a:count each group x}
q)min mode l
1
q)mode l
1 2
```

As you can see above I would just define a mode function and then use `min` before the function call to return an atom of the lowest value.